# Nuxt JS asyncData return old data when fetching from api. How to receive last version of data?

Tags: nuxt.js

The data from api still coming as an old request, is Nuxt JS caching something? How to disable?
The problem only happens if in production.

```
async asyncData({ params, app, error }) {
   // Getting data
   var theme  = await axios.get(`${settings.firebaseConfig.databaseURL}/theme.json`)
   var page  = await axios.get(`${settings.firebaseConfig.databaseURL}/publishedPages/${params.page}.json`)

     return {
    // Even if the api update the data, old version still coming :(
      page: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(page.data)), 
      theme: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(theme.data)),        
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is cache related, you could try something like this:

```
var now = Date.now()
var theme  = await 
axios.get(`${settings.firebaseConfig.databaseURL}/theme.json?cachebust=${now}`)
```